# Creating a 3 level sub-gouping of an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json, pdo

need help figuring out where i'm going wrong on this.

I get this result from a PDO fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

```
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and get this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [father] => 1
            [child] => 1
            [timeOfchild] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [father] => 1
            [child] => 1
            [grandChild] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [father] => 1
            [child] => 1
            [grandChild] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [father] => 1
            [child] => 1
            [grandChild] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [father] => 1
            [child] => 2
            [grandChild] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [father] => 1
            [child] => 2
            [grandChild] => 3
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [father] => 1
            [child] => 2
            [grandChild] => 4
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [father] => 2
            [child] => 1
            [grandChild] => 4
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [father] => 2
            [child] => 1
            [grandChild] => 3
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [father] => 2
            [child] => 1
            [grandChild] => 2
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [father] => 2
            [child] => 2
            [grandChild] => 2
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [father] => 2
            [child] => 2
            [grandChild] => 3
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [father] => 2
            [child] => 2
            [grandChild] => 4
        )

)
```

now to do the grouping i use a foreach loop

```
$family = array();
    // Loop JSON objects
    foreach($result as $object) {

        $father_key = $object['father'];
        $child_key = $object['child'];
        $grandChild_key = $object['grandChild'];
        $children = 'children';

     if(!array_key_exists($father_key, $family)) {
        $fatherObject = array();

        $fatherObject['title'] = 'Father' .$father_key;
        $fatherObject['key'] = $father_key;
        $fatherObject['children'] = array();                        
        // Save this new object
        $family[$father_key] = $fatherObject;
     }

        $week_children = $family[$father_key][$children];

        if(!array_key_exists($child_key, $week_children)) {

            $childObject = array();
            $childObject['title'] = 'Child' .$child_key;
            $childObject['key'] = $child_key;
            $childObject['children'] = array();
            // Save this new object
            $family[$father_key]['children'][$child_key] = $childObject;
        }

        if(isset($family[$father_key][$children][$child_key][$children])){
            $day_children = $family[$father_key][$children][$child_key][$children];
            if(!array_key_exists($grandChild_key, $day_children)) {

                $grandChildObject = array();
                $grandChildObject['title'] = 'GrandChild' .$grandChild_key;
                $grandChildObject['key'] = $grandChild_key;
                // Save this new object
                $family[$father_key][$children][$child_key]['children'][$grandChild_key] = $grandChildObject;
            }
        }

    }

 echo json_encode($family);
```

Expected out should be in the form of:

```
[

        {"title": "Father 1", "key": "1", "children": [
            {"title": "child 1", "key" : "1", "children" : [
                        {"title" : "grandchild 1" , "key" : "key 1" },
                        {"title" : "grandchild 2" , "key" : "key 2" }
                  ]},
            {"title": "child 2", "children" : [
                        {"title" : "grandchild 1" , "key" : "key 1" },
                        {"title" : "grandchild 2" , "key" : "key 2" }
                  ]},
            {"title": "child 3", "children" : [
                        {"title" : "grandchild 1" , "key" : "key 1" },
                        {"title" : "grandchild 2" , "key" : "key 2" }
                  ]},
        ]},
        {"title": "Father 2", "key": "1", "children": [
            {"title": "child 1", "key" : "1", "children" : [
                        {"title" : "grandchild 1" , "key" : "key 1" },
                        {"title" : "grandchild 2" , "key" : "key 2" }
                  ]},
            {"title": "child 2", "children" : [
                        {"title" : "grandchild 1" , "key" : "key 1" },
                        {"title" : "grandchild 2" , "key" : "key 2" }
                  ]},
            {"title": "child 3", "children" : [
                        {"title" : "grandchild 1" , "key" : "key 1" },
                        {"title" : "grandchild 2" , "key" : "key 2" }
                  ]},
            ]}
];
```

but i'm getting something in the form of when i JSON_encode($family) as output from the PHP file.

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "title":"Father 1",
      "key":"1",
      "children":{  
         "1":{  
            "title":"Child 1",
            "key":"1",
            "children":{  
               "1":{  
                  "title":"GrandChild 1",
                  "key":"1"
               },
               "2":{  
                  "title":"GrandChild 2",
                  "key":"2"
               }
            }
         },
         "2":{  
            "title":"Child 2",
            "key":"2",
            "children":{  
               "1":{  
                  "title":"GrandChild 1",
                  "key":"1"
               },
               "2":{  
                  "title":"GrandChild 2",
                  "key":"2"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "2":{  
      "title":"Father 2",
      "key":"2",
      "children":{  
         "1":{  
            "title":"Child 2",
            "key":"1",
            "children":{  
               "1":{  
                  "title":"GrandChild 1",
                  "key":"2"
               },
               "2":{  
                  "title":"GrandChild 2",
                  "key":"3"
               }
            }
         },
         "2":{  
            "title":"Child 2",
            "key":"2",
            "children":{  
               "1":{  
                  "title":"GrandChild 1",
                       ................
        };
```

Comment: What is 'timeOfchild' ? Also why does not they have own id?

Comment: it should not have been in there forgot to remove it, this is for another sub-group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with that solution instead because i was having issues using the array with JS.

```
        $family = array();
        // Loop JSON objects

        foreach($result as $object) {

            $father_key = $object["father"];
            $child = $object["child"];
            $grandchild = $object["grandChild"];
            $children = "children";

            if (!multi_in_array($father, $family) ) {
                $fatherObject = array();
                $fatherObject["title"] = "father " .$father;
                $fatherObject["key"] = $father;
                $fatherObject["children"] = array();
                $family[] = $fatherObject;
            }
        }

        foreach($result as $object) {
            $father = $object["father"];
            $child = $object["child"];
            $grandchild = $object["grandChild"];
            $children = "children";

            foreach($family as $index => $value){           
                $myFather = $value["key"];
                $childrens = $value[$children];
                if($father === $myFather){
                    if (!multi_in_array($child, $childrens) ) {
                        $childObject = array();
                        $childObject["title"] = "child " .$child;
                        $childObject["key"] = $child;
                        $childObject["children"] = array();
                        // Save this new object
                        $family[$index]["children"][] = $childObject;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach($result as $object) {
            $father = $object["father"];
            $child = $object["child"];
            $grandchild = $object["grandChild"];
            $children = "children";

            foreach($family as $index => $value){
                $myFather = $value["key"];              
                $childrens = $value[$children];

                foreach($childrens as $childIndex => $childValues){
                    $myChild = $childValues["key"];
                    $child_childrens = $childValues[$children];

                    if($father === $myFather && $child === $myChild){
                        if (!multi_in_array($grandchild, $child_childrens) ) {
                            $grandChildObject = array();
                            $grandChildObject['title'] = 'grandChild ' .$grandchild;
                            $grandChildObject['key'] = $grandchild;
                            // Save this new object
                            $family[$index][$children][$childIndex]['children'][] = $grandChildObject;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

with the previous solution the arrays key were not starting with 0 instead i would have [1] => ... and [2]=> ... which ended up generating errors when my js code was trying to interpreted the array. I tried to use array_values to remap the array and have all the array keys start at 0 but this function is not recursive and would only do the first level. therefore i'm going with this unless someone can point how to remap the final array to have all numeric keys start at zero.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your script / intention, but I get the feeling that when you set the
the children object you wanna write :

```
 // Save this new object
$family[$father_key]['children'][$child_key] = $childObject;
```

and not

```
 // Save this new object
$family[$father_key]['children'][] = $childObject;
```